# matlab making repetitions of data from one array into another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat

I would appreaciate a lot if you help. I am beginner in programming. I am using Matlab. So, I have an array which is 431x1 type - double; there i have numbers 1 to 6; for ex: 1 4 5 3 2 6 6 3 3 5 4 1 ...; what I want to do is I need to make a new array where I would have each element repeat for 11 times; for ex: a(1:11)=1; a(12:22)=4; a(23:33)=5; or to illustrate differently : a=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4...];
I tried doing it in a loop but had some problems, which way could you suggest, do you know any function I could take advantage of?

Comment: You can use [repelem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would help if you could format your code is separate blocks to make your question easier to read...

---

Let's say you had an array of length Nx1 as:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 ...]';
```

You could construct a loop and concatenate as:

```
for i = 1 : length(x)

for i = 1: length(x)
    y(1 + (i - 1) * 11 : 1 + i * 11) = x(i);    % Copy to a moving block
end
y(end) = [];    % Delete the superfluous one at the end
```

You could also look at functions like `repmat` in the MATLAB help for replicating arrays.

Comment: thank you! I also tried with repmat inside a loop but again I had trouble with correct indexing to store the replicated values;

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`NRep`is how many times you want it repeated):

```
 x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 NRep = 5;
 y = reshape(repmat(x,[NRep,1]),[1,length(x)*NRep])
```

Since it's a little cumbersome to write that out, I also particularly enjoy to use this "hack":

```
 x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 NRep = 5;
 y = kron(x, ones(1,NRep));
```

Hope that helps!

P.S.: This is designed for row vectors only. Though if you need column vectors it's easy to modify.

**edit**: Of course, if you're post-R2015a you can just use `y=repelem(x,NRep)`. I tend to forget about those because I work on older Matlabs (and sometimes it's not such a bad idea to be a bit backward compatible). Thanks to @rahnema1 for reminding me.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! this is repelem function which I didnt know about was exactly what I needed :D yayy, your code also worked it gives correct number of repetitions but the problem was that it repeats the whole sequence 11 times rather than replicating each element 11 times; anyway thanks a lot!